# Function parameter Class<Type> won't accept child of type

Tags: java, class, reflection

I have one method with a parameter `Class<SearchForm> formType`, and in the method I call `formType.newInstance()` to get an instance of the form. I need to be able to pass in child classes of SearchForm, but when I try to pass in `MySearchForm.class` (where MySearchForm extends SearchForm), eclipse tells me I cannot pass in `Class<MySearchForm>` for a parameter of type `Class<SearchForm>`.

How can I pass in a class extending the desired parent class and then instantiate an object of that class?

Comment: What about `Class<? extends SearchForm>`?

Comment: That works. Add it as an answer so I can credit you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an [upper bound generic wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) `Class<? extends SearchForm>`

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass in a `Class<MySearchForm>`, because it's not a `Class<SearchForm>`, even if a `MySearchForm` is a `SearchForm`.

However, you can use a wildcard parameter in your method, defined something like this:

```
... yourMethod(Class<? extends SearchForm> formType)
```